# Install Node.js on a different hard drive from C to D

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I have node and npm with existing packages currently installed to the C drive on Windows. My C drive is an SSD with a low amount of space. How can I move the node installation to a different drive? Would I need to reinstall node and all packages? The current node installer doesn't seem to specify drives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can move the node.exe to the d drive.  Then check your environment path.  Type set in a command window or in computer properties. Make sure you have the folder that contains node.exe in your path.  Running node in a command window will work from any folder then.

For installed npm packages, ie.. node_modules folder..  That just needs to be in a directory above where your writing your code, so try putting that folder in d:\   Assuming your going to be writing your apps on the d drive now.

In .npmrc file, change prefix setting to desired folder. Global packages get installed in node_modules under that folder

Comment: What about my global npm packages? Will that be installed in the AppData of D drive or stay in the C drive? That's what I'm most worried about. Because those global npm packages are the biggest.

Comment: Appended to answer..  Edit .npmrc file.

Comment: Ok I will try this thanks. I'll probably to reinstall Node however. Will let you know if I have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are talking about, the node installer has this page. [image: Node Installer]

What version of node are you trying to install? This screenshot is taken from v0.11.7 of node.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post was basically forever ago, but I found a much easier way than manipulating the path. Simply uninstall NPM using the npm uninstaller, reinstall on your other drive with a new folder called nodejs. It'll create the folder in there appropriately and npm will be successfully installed on you D drive.

Answer (score 0):

Search  -> Environmental variables of system
click on path ( both )
click on new
add the path of your node.exe file
***boom you are done****

node -v to check