# Setting up node and npm to external hard drive. windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, environment-variables

I was wondering if anyone can make a good guide for setting up nodejs and npm to an external hard drive. I am having trouble finding any posts that are up to date, or a complete guide. If anyone is able to correctly give a detailed explanation it would be greatly appreciated. I have windows 8.1.
Please include setting up enviromental variables.
Creating a good organize directory path.
and a way to insure no data gets uploaded to your laptops memory (my lap tops memory is pretty low.) and all to your portable hard drive. 
Thank you.

Comment: Check out this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/18965126/10055855](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18965126/10055855)