# How to install node.js in a custom directory through powershell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, installation

I am making a script to install NodeJS on several machines through PowerShell.
By default NodeJS gets installed in C:\Program Files\nodejs folder. Can I define a custom directory for the installation?

I am running this command:

```
msiexec.exe /i $nodejs_download_filename /L*V "logger.log" /passive | out-null
```

Is there any argument to add to this line in order to specify the target directory instead of the default one?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this

**[Install Node.js on a different hard drive from C to D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965126/install-node-js-on-a-different-hard-drive-from-c-to-d)**

```
You can move the node.exe to the d drive. Then check your environment path. 
Type set in a command window or in computer properties. 
Make sure you have the folder that contains node.exe in your path. 
Running node in a command window will work from any folder then.

For installed npm packages, ie.. node_modules folder.. 
That just needs to be in a directory above where your writing your code, so try putting that folder in d:\ Assuming your going to be writing your apps on the d drive now.

In .npmrc file, change prefix setting to desired folder. Global packages get installed in node_modules under that folder.
```