# Installing vue on D drive using npm

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am trying to install vue on my D drive.
Still rather new at this so I am unsure of some of the details.
I have Node is installed on 'D:/nodejs' and it works; `npm -v` returns 6.14.13

However, using `npm install -g @vue/cli` by default installs the files on the C drive. Vue works; `vue --version` returns @vue/cli 4.5.13. However, I want to run everything from the D drive to avoid permission issues and save space on the C drive (it's running rather low). I have a directory set up under 'D:/npm'

I have tried using `npm install -prefix D:/npm -g @vue/cli` but running `vue --version` results in: `vue : The term 'vue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` My guess is that npm is still trying to use the default C drive path for vue.cmd, but I have not been able to find a concrete explanation or solution.

I uninstalled all vue files and tried using `npm config set prefix 'D:/npm'`, then used `npm install -g @vue/cli`. So far so good; 'D:/npm' has vue.cmd and the associated files. However, I still get the error telling me the command isn't recognised when I run `vue --version`.

Furthermore, the npmrc file for both the user and npm have been edited to include `prefix=D:\npm` and I ran `npm config set cache D:\npm\npm-cache --global`. Does not work.

How do I fix this and how do I configure npm to use the D drive?

Comment: This answer shows how to do that..https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971921/7364894 May be create a node_modules folder in D: drive and see if that works.