# How to install Node package to a specific drive?

Tags: node.js, npx

I'm a complete newbie trying to break into the world of all the wonderful new technologies coming forward, and it seems part of that meant installing Node, as it's something a lot of programmers are using. I installed it on my D: drive, great! Issue: When I use npx install, it wants to send what I'm installing to the C: drive, which has like 6 GB of space left.

Is there a way I can tell Node where to send things when I use npx to install things?

I tried installing Node to D: drive, used npx to install something, and Node tried to put it on my C: drive automatically. Also tried changing the directory in nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc.

Comment: this could give some [insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: Have you tried adding an [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc) file to your root folder, and giving it a `prefix` attribute to specify where willl your packages get installed ?

Comment: There was one in nodejs\node_modules\npm that I modified as such, now that you mention it, but that didn't work out. Would npx function on a different directory, perhaps...? Where precisely would I put this npmrc file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Node.js on a different hard drive from C to D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965126/install-node-js-on-a-different-hard-drive-from-c-to-d)

Comment: @Hamada It doesn't seem to, because my Node.exe is already on D: and it's still putting the installed packages on C:, however I did recently come upon a thing buried in discussions for the actual package I'm trying to install that might fix my problem. I'll try fixing with that and update if it works out.